# datename function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I wanted to get the week from the given date, for this I tried with the DATENAME function to get the WEEK like,

```
 Select DateName(WEEK,'2012-03-09')
```

am getting the output as 10. I want to get the starting date and ending date of this week like, `2012-03-04 to 2012-03-10` Is it possible?

Comment: which database server are you using?

Comment: is it possible to display the Starting and Ending date within a single column like "2012-03-04 to 2012-03-10"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
DECLARE @MyDate Date = '2012-03-09';

-- This gets you the SUNDAY of the week your date falls in...
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @MyDate) - 1), @MyDate);

-- This gets you the SATURDAY of the week your date falls in...
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, (7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @MyDate)), @MyDate);

-- This will show the range as a single column
SELECT
  CONVERT(NVarChar, DATEADD(DAY, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @MyDate) - 1), @MyDate))
  + ' through ' +
  CONVERT(NVarChar, DATEADD(DAY, (7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @MyDate)), @MyDate));
```

Comment: is it possible to display the Starting and Ending date within a single column like "2012-03-04 to 2012-03-10"

Comment: @Shanish Yes, see my edit. Although keep in mind that the combined result is actually text so you won't be able to manipulate the dates without parsing.

Answer (score 1):

try the following, change getdate to your date

```
Select 
DateAdd(d, 1- DatePart(dw,GetDate()),GetDate()) FirstDayOfWeek,
DateAdd(d, 7- DatePart(dw,GetDate()),GetDate()) LastDayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not rely on your default setting of datefirst.

```
set datefirst 4 -- this row does nothing in this query. 
                -- It will hurt the queries using datepart though
declare @t table(dt datetime)
insert @t values('2012-03-09 11:12'), ('2012-03-10 11:12'),('2012-03-11 11:12')

-- week from sunday to saturday 
Select dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dt),-1),
       dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dt),+5)
from @t
```